# What is the difference between these two methods of memory allocation?

Tags: c, pointers

The following are memory allocation method for a `p[10][10]` array.

```
//First
char** p;
int i;
p=(char**)malloc(10*sizeof(char*));
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    p[i]=(char*)malloc(10*sizeof(char));

//Second
char** p;
int i;
p=(char**)malloc(10*sizeof(char*));
*p=(char*)malloc(100*sizeof(char));
for(i=1;i<10;i++)
    p[i]=p[0]+10*i;
```

What is the difference between the two?

Comment: These aren't "arrays" though

Comment: Standard warning: Do **not** cast `void *` as returned by `malloc` & friends! **C is not C++.** Note: `sizeof(char)` is defined to yield `1`.

Comment: Oh, and none of these are arrays. Even less 2-dimensional arrays. That would be `char a[10][10]` (as you wrote in the first sentence).

Comment: @awesomeyi; These are dynamically allocated arrays.

Comment: i am using this platform for the first time, next time i will keep in mind to put up a suitable heading, and @awesomeyi thanks for editing the heading

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Neither of these are C++. The first allocates an array of 10 `char*`, and then assigns each of those to a separate dynamically allocated array of 10 `char`. Each array of 10 is independent, so you have no guarantee for what the difference is between `p[0][9]` and `p[1][0]`:

```
  p
+------+
| p[0] |  --> [][][][][][][][][][]
+------+
| p[1] |  --> [][][][][][][][][][]
+------+
|      |  --> [][][][][][][][][][]
+------+
 ...  
+------+
| p[9] |  --> [][][][][][][][][][]
+------+
```

In the second case, you have one contiguous array of 100 `char`, and your 10 `char*` each point to different segments in there:

```
   0  1  2      10     20
  +--+--+--+   +--+   +--+
  |  |  |  |...|  |...|  |...    <== dynamically allocated array of 100 char
  +--+--+--+   +--+   +--+
    |         /       /
    \        /       /
  +------+------+------+
p | p[0] | p[1] | p[2] |...      <== dynamically allocated array of 10 char*
  +------+------+------+
```

Here you do have a guarantee that the next `char` after `p[0][9]` is `p[1][0]`.

Though neither of these are really arrays. To do that, you'd want:

```
char p[10][10];
```

which would give the equivalent behavior of that second block - minus all the extra overhead of the 10 `char*`s and the dynamic memory allocation. In C++, we'd prefer to write that one as:

```
std::array<std::array<char, 10>, 10> p;
```

Comment: They are actually C++ - just that use of `malloc()` is deprecated.

Answer (score 4):

You are dynamically allocating arrays in your snippets. The difference is that first snippet allocates memory for each of 10 `char` pointers in a zig-zag (depending on the availability of memory space) manner.  Second snippet allocates contiguous memory for each of 10 `char` pointers.

See the pic to get it more clear

```
int **array1 = malloc(nrows * sizeof(int *));
    for(i = 0; i < nrows; i++)
        array1[i] = malloc(ncolumns * sizeof(int));
```

[image]

```
int **array2 = malloc(nrows * sizeof(int *));
    array2[0] = malloc(nrows * ncolumns * sizeof(int));
    for(i = 1; i < nrows; i++)
        array2[i] = array2[0] + i * ncolumns;
```

[image]

Further reading: [How can I dynamically allocate a multidimensional array?](http://www.c-faq.com/aryptr/dynmuldimary.html).

Comment: @Barry; Why do you think my answer makes no sense?

Comment: The 10 `char*`s are allocated in the same fashion, it's the memory those `char*`s point to which is allocated differently.

Comment: @TartanLlama;  When did I say that the 10 `char *`s are allocated differently?

Comment: "The difference is that first snippet allocates memory for 10 char pointer [...] second snippet allocates contiguous memory for 10 `char` pointer". That reads to me like you are saying the 10 are allocated differently.

Comment: @TartanLlama; Oh! Now it seems that I am a noob in pointer and arrays tag!

Comment: @haccks I'm not questioning your expertise, just saying that your wording seemed to suggest something which isn't true. The edit makes your intent clearer :)

Answer (score 3):

In this code snippet

```
char** p;
int i;
p=(char**)malloc(10*sizeof(char*));
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    p[i]=(char*)malloc(10*sizeof(char));
```

there are allocated memory for one-dimensional array of 10 pointers of type  `char *`:

```
p=(char**)malloc(10*sizeof(char*));
```

Each pointer in turn is initialized by the address of allocated memory for one-dimensional array of 10 elements of type `char`:

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    p[i]=(char*)malloc(10*sizeof(char));
```

In this cade snippet

```
char** p;
int i;
p=(char**)malloc(10*sizeof(char*));
*p=(char*)malloc(100*sizeof(char));
for(i=1;i<10;i++)
    p[i]=p[0]+10*i;
```

there is at first allocated memory for one-dimensional array of 10 elements of type `char *` as in the first code snippet.

```
p=(char**)malloc(10*sizeof(char*));
```

However then only the first element of the array is initialized by the address of allocated memory for on-dimensional array of 100 elements of type `char`.

```
*p=(char*)malloc(100*sizeof(char));
```

The above statement is equivalent to

```
p[0]=(char*)malloc(100*sizeof(char));
```

And then other 9 pointers are initialized by integer expressions `10*i`

```
for(i=1;i<10;i++)
    p[i]=p[0]+10*i;
```

It is evident that this does not make sense.  The values of these 9 elements are invalid because they are not pointers to objects. That is the purpose of these initializations is unclear.

Take into account that you could allocate memory for one two-dimensional array the following way

```
char ( *p )[10] = malloc( 100 * sizeof( char ) );
```

The advantage of this allocation is that you need only one call to function `free` that to free all allocated memory. And moreover this pointer can be used as argument for a function that has a parameter as a two diemsional array.

For example

```
void func( char a[][10] );
```

You may call this function like

```
func( p );
```

However you may not call the function if p has type `char **` because this type is not compatible with the type of the parameter.